# snmp server how to encode request packet?

Tags: sockets, request, snmp

i am writing a snmp server on port 161 that just shows five stars and I can get the star number by snmpget command line and also set them by snmpset. when i receive request packet in string i cannot encode it to readable . the snmp packet format starts with integer for version and then an octet string and so on...

```
public class MyServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
```

{
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(161);

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);

while(true)
{

socket.receive(packet);
byte[] data = packet.getData();


String s=new String(data,"UTF-8");
System.out.println(s+"\t"+packet.getAddress()+"\t"+packet.getPort());
```

the output is some like this but stranger!!!

0'public?<\

Comment: SNMP packets are not text, so your code snippet above is completely wrong. Learn the protocol via IETF RFC documents or an open source library such as snmp4j.

Answer (score 0):

The SNMP is not that simple as other protocols. In fact this is the one of the most complex protocols to implement and use.

Constructing a SNMP message requires some knowledge of the data types specified by **ASN.1**. ASN.1 primitive data types include Integer, Octet (byte, character) String, Null, Boolean and Object Identifier. The Object Identifier type is central to the SNMP message, because a field of the Object Identifier type holds the OID used to address a parameter in the SNMP agent. To expand the programmer's ability to organize data, ASN.1 allows primitive data types to be grouped together into complex data types.

ASN.1 offers several complex data types necessary for building SNMP messages. One complex data type is the Sequence. A Sequence is simply a list of data fields. Each field in a Sequence can have a different data type. ASN.1 also defines the SNMP PDU (Protocol Data unit) data types, which are complex data types specific to SNMP. The PDU field contains the body of an SNMP message. Two PDU data types available are GetRequest and SetRequest, which hold all the necessary data to get and set parameters, respectively. Ultimately the SNMP message is a structure built entirely from fields of ASN.1 data types. However, specifying the correct data type is not enough. If the SNMP message is a Sequence of fields with varying data types, how can a recipient know where one field ends and another begins, or the data type of each field? Avoid these problems by conforming to the **Basic Encoding Rules (BER)**.
The most fundamental rule states that each field is encoded in three parts: Type, Length, and Value (TLV). Type specifies the data type of the field using a single byte identifier. Length specifies the length in bytes of the following Value section, and Value is the actual value communicated (the number, string, OID, etc).

So please do not reinvent the wheel as there are several very well written libraries that implement SNMPv1, SNMPv2C and SNMPv3 in full accordance to standards. These are **NET-SNMP**, **SNMP4J** and some others. Use them.